# grails - Generated instance in View definition

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, groovy

generate-all in grails will Generate a Controller together with View (CRUD), I am trying to learn the impact of each generated block of code and now I can't seem to find the definition of {accountInstanceList} in the index.gsp.

/views/account/index.gsp

```
        <g:each in="${accountInstanceList}" status="i" var="accountInstance">
            <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                <td><g:link action="show" id="${accountInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: accountInstance, field: "firstname")}</g:link></td>

                <td>${fieldValue(bean: accountInstance, field: "middlename")}</td>

                <td>${fieldValue(bean: accountInstance, field: "lastname")}</td>

                <td>${fieldValue(bean: accountInstance, field: "email")}</td>

                <td>${fieldValue(bean: accountInstance, field: "role")}</td>

            </tr>
        </g:each>
```

From what I have learned the definition of the said instance should be included in Controller

/controller/.../AccountController.groovy

```
package ers

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class AccountController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond Account.list(params), model:[accountInstanceCount: Account.count()]
    }

    def show(Account accountInstance) {
        respond accountInstance
    }

    def create() {
        respond new Account(params)
    }

    @Transactional
    def save(Account accountInstance) {
        if (accountInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (accountInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond accountInstance.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }

        accountInstance.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'account.label', default: 'Account'), accountInstance.id])
                redirect accountInstance
            }
            '*' { respond accountInstance, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    }

    def edit(Account accountInstance) {
        respond accountInstance
    }

    @Transactional
    def update(Account accountInstance) {
        if (accountInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (accountInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond accountInstance.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }

        accountInstance.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'Account.label', default: 'Account'), accountInstance.id])
                redirect accountInstance
            }
            '*'{ respond accountInstance, [status: OK] }
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    def delete(Account accountInstance) {

        if (accountInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        accountInstance.delete flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'Account.label', default: 'Account'), accountInstance.id])
                redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
        }
    }

    protected void notFound() {
        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'account.label', default: 'Account'), params.id])
                redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
        }
    }
}
```

{accountInstanceList} is not in the index action in the controller, where is it defined? Is there hidden class that is also generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The render method figures out the type of 'thing' you're trying to pass to the view and creates a suitable name, in the case of a list of domain objects it's DomainNameInstanceList, see the class `DefaultHtmlRenderer`

Also see the [scaffollding](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/scaffolding.html) section of the docs

```
...the standard scaffold views expect model variables of the form
<propertyName>InstanceList for collections and <propertyName>Instance
for single instances
```

Comment: in other words i will not see the physical definition of the instance?

Comment: what do you mean by see?

Comment: what i mean is i cannot goto the definition of accountInstanceList?

Comment: Not as such, it's along the lines of manually returning `[accountInstanceList: Account.findAllBy(params)]` or some other method on your domain that returns a list

Comment: i'm grateful, save me a lot of time